# Soft Question: Taking Multivariable Calculus vs. Introduction to Proofs Class

Tags: multivariable-calculus, soft-question

Would taking multivariable calculus be boring in comparison to an introduction to proofs class for someone good at Calc. I and II? The multivariable calculus class would not cover topics like Green's Theorem, Stoke's Theorem, Divergence, Curl but rather only double and triple integrals, the del operator, gradient, and directional derivatives. Would it be more interesting intellectually for someone to take the introduction to proofs class which would cover set theory,cardinalities, basic graph theory, formal logic, axiom systems, relations and related things?

I'm thinking that because the multivaribale class doesn't even cover green's theorem and stoke's theorem it would be too easy and a waste of time to take.

Comment: I would say it depends on what your interests are and how far you want to go with math. If you plan on doing more mathematics, I would go with the second option, as it gives a better preparation.

Comment: What is your goal, pure math, applied math, physics, engineering?  If you see your self as a pure math person, then introduction to proofs is probably the way way to go.  If you lean toward physics / engineering I would say skip introduction to proofs all together.  If you are applied math then you should think about taking both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are important but as you mention, since your multivariable calculus class won't cover a big part of the real analysis II theorems, it may indeed be boring. I think it would be better for you to take proofs class, because it covers an important theoritical part of Mathematics that will serve as an introduction to the world of the real Theory of Mathematics. (as a guy into Topology and Knot Theory, I like theoritical stuff)

Answer (score 0):

I *suspect* that the multivariable calculus course you describe is heavier on application than theory.

Taking some very broad strokes here, if you're looking to go into engineering, which is application-heavy in practice, then you'll see and solve more practical problems in that course, which will provide benefit going that route.

If you're looking to go into mathematics, then learning to do proofs will help you there, because that's a major way that mathematicians communicate their work.

Having said all that, you can always learn about proofs in an application-heavy class, or apply what you've learned in a theory-heavy class.